# UITableView contentHeight is bigger than expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement an infinite scrolling view, and need to figure out what the user reaches the bottom.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat actualPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y + navBarHeight;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
```

If you look at the code above, I intend to find that `actualPosition == contentHeight` when the user's at the end of the screen. However, when I printed out the values I got the following:

`contentHeight 3000.000000, actual 2490.000000`

Navbar's height is only `60.0` so that's not the reason. What could be other missing pieces?

Comment: Have you included header footer heights in actual heights?

Comment: Hm.. So there's `NavigationController` and 'TabBarController`. I included navBarHeight and statusBarHeight, but not TabBarHeight yet. With TabbarHeight also included, the difference is now `505`, where contentHeight is 3000.0 and actual position at the bottom is 2495.0

Comment: exactly what are you going to do? means what you want ? You want to detect whether user reaches at the end of the screen?

Comment: Hey can you specify the heights of individual row and also some more code ...? because here i made a demo that works perfectly in my code

Comment: It's static: 150. It still doesn't make up for the difference. Your previous answer was an excellt workaround though. It works for my usecase.

Comment: Now i got you use this method `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and calculate `actualPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y + (150*numberOfVisibleRow)` then and then only you can get actualPosition = totalContentSize there is no need to add navBarheight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `willDisplayCell` delegate of `UITableView` to detect end of scrolling rather than calculating content Heights Like

if your array contains 50 records then in `willDisplayCell` you can check

```
if (arrRows.count-1 == indexPath.row)
{
    // This is the end of scrolling
}
```